# Media player placed in iframe doesn't playing with Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, iframe, frontend

I'm trying to add MP3 media player to my app from external service using iframe (for my issue it is Krakenfiles website). I want to pass the link to the src using variable.

I'm using SafeResourceUrl and DomSanitizer in order to handle security, what is in this case required by angular.

```
safeSrc: SafeResourceUrl;
constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
  this.safeSrc =  this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(
    'https://krakenfiles.com/getEmbedPlayer/1f02d877ff?width=450&amp;autoplay=false&amp;date=18-08-2020');
  }
```

After declaring a variable, I'm flipping the variable to the html code (inside iframe declaration):

```
<iframe [src]="safeSrc" width="450" height="100" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

[image of broken media player from krakenfiles service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHgJ6.png)

As you can see above, iframe is displayed on the page, but the content is not visible and the player does not react to anything.

I suspected the error was in the link, so I tried to call the link without passing a variable to iframe src and surprisingly it worked (below code is working correctly).

```
<iframe src="https://krakenfiles.com/getEmbedPlayer/1f02d877ff?width=450&amp;autoplay=false&amp;date=18-08-2020" width="450" height="100" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

I think, maybe there are still some limitations from the Angular related to passing to variable

[image of media player working correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2sbu.png)

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace `&amp;` with `&`.

Angular and Web Browser can understand this sign, while in HTML code we need insert the character reference for "An ampersand" (`&amp;`)

Comment: Yeah, that's it !
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be the source file is not there. It's not an angular issue. When you go directly to the page `https://krakenfiles.com/getEmbedPlayer/1f02d877ff?width=450&amp;autoplay=false&amp;date=18-08-2020%27` you see the broken file.

Comment: But if you add link inside <iframe> block it is working.